# Problems creating win32_trustee object

Tags: windows, powershell, network-share

I try to create it like this:

`new-object system.management.managementclass win32_trustee`

and I get this error:

`new-object : The following exception occurred while retrieving the type name hierarchy: "Not found ".
At line:1 char:1
+ new-object system.management.managementclass win32_trustee
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Object], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetTypeNameHierarchy,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand`

You're supposed to get an object with TypeName: 
`System.Management.ManagementClass#ROOT\cimv2\Win32_Trustee`

But instead I get an error. It seems I have lost or deleted the win32_trustee class by accident but don't remember how. I'm just trying to get it back. You can check the other things that were suggested at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41050688/the-following-exception-occurred-while-retrieving-the-type-name-hierarchy-not#

ANY help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try recompiling the MOF file. Win32_Trustee is part of the secrcw32.mof located in %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\

Open an elevated command prompt and run the following:

`mofcomp.exe %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\secrcw32.mof`

More information on recompiling WMI MOFs is available on the [Ask the Performance Team Blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2009/04/13/wmi-recompiling-wmi-mofs/)